# OpenLayers 3: Zoom map to coordinates in array

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need to zoom my OpenLayers map (which uses a Google Maps baselayer) to fit all of a given list of coordinates into the view.

I've stored the coordinates in an array of longitude and latitude pairs named `pointsDecimal` which looks like this:

```
pointsDecimal: Array[50]
  0: 148.77638
  1: -34.491728
  2: 148.77896
  3: -34.492302
  4: 148.778090711323
  ...
```

Even-numbered indices (0, 2, 4 etc) are longitude, and odd-numbered indices (1, 3, 5 etc) are latitude.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
map.getView().fit(pointsDecimal, map.getSize());
```

But for some reason this puts me at maximum zoom level at the coordinates [0,0] - in the Gulf of Guinea, not in southeastern New South Wales where I'd like to be!

I know this would be much easier if I was using an OpenLayers source (e.g. `source.getExtent()`) in place of my `pointsDecimal` array, but this is not an option in this case for reasons I won't go into right now - I can only use the array.

Can anyone give me any hints please?

**EDIT:** I think I'm nearly there, thanks to Anupam. This is what I have now:

```
var extent = [pointsLongMin,pointsLatMin,pointsLongMax,pointsLatMax];
map.getView().fit(extent,map.getSize());
```

The values I'm passing to the array are as follows:

```
pointsLongMin: 148.771162
pointsLatMin: -34.5029736405108
pointsLongMax: 148.77896
pointsLatMax: -34.491728
```

But I'm still getting dumped out in the ocean at [0,0]. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use map.getView().fit(extent,size). 
extent denotes four points as [minx, miny, maxx,maxy].

It is actually a rectangle. try

```
var extent=[148.77638,-34.491728,148.77896,-34.492302];

map.getView().fit(extent,map.getSize());
```

Comment: I'm sure this is getting me closer, but it's still dumping me out in the same place in the ocean. I copied your code above exactly... Can you think of any reason this might not be working? Thanks for your help.

Comment: reason is extent actually I just picked them from the array you shared. You just need to pass correct extent.

Comment: Still can't get it working - see my edits above. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4):

most propable reason is that your map is projected on `EPSG:3857`while your extent `EPSG:4326`. So you need to transform your extent to your map projection.

```
var coordMin = ol.proj.fromLonLat([148.77638,-34.491728], 'EPSG:3857');
var coordMax = ol.proj.fromLonLat([148.77896,-34.492302], 'EPSG:3857');
var extent=[coordMin[0],coordMin[1],coordMax[0],coordMax[1]];
map.getView().fit(extent,map.getSize());
```

You may find a more elegand way to do the extent transformation. Unless you provide your full code we can only guess what is your map projection. I am just guessing is EPSG:3857 cause thats the default ol3 use.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. Can't believe I hadn't thought of that - I'd been correcting for projection differences in all of the other parts of my code, not sure why I didn't think to do it for this part. The code that worked for me was the same as yours above except I replaced the coordinates in your code with variable names, e.g. `var coordMin = ol.proj.fromLonLat([pointsLongMin,pointsLatMin], 'EPSG:3857');` Thanks a million.